# Ant script for telnet connection

Tags: maven, ant, telnet

How can I use ant for a telnet connection and execute a command on the target machine? Or should I use maven instead?

Answer (score 1):

The ant [telnet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/telnet.html) task can do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient

Comment: Check out the [library dependancies](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies).  telnet requires the [commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) jar file to be on the classpath when running this task.

Comment: I have a ant-commons-net.jar in my apache-ant-1.8.4\lib folder which also is in PATH. I doesn't work.

Comment: ccman, not ant-commons-net.jar, but commons-net.jar. Notice there's no "ant-" in front. You have to download the third-party Apache Commons Net library from the link provided by krock.